# In MAC firefox, Anchor tags are not focused

Tags: firefox, accessibility

When the user presses the "tab" key, anchor tags are not identified.

Despite setting the "tabindex" attribute, the anchor tags remain unfocused.

Comment: https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2014/10/03/link-tabbing-firefox-osx.html